# iReport won't load my .dat file - field values won't show

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to get values from variables in my bean class into *iReport* (using JavaBean as datasoure). I have the bean class which in its constructor calls a loadReceipt() method - which loads data from a .dat file the user saves. I then have other methods in the bean class which use the data from loadReceipt() to calculate figures and saves them into double variables.

Each of the variables has a getMethod which I call in the factory class and is added to a JavaBean collection which *iReport* uses.

However my problem is that when I drag the fields into my PDF template and Preview it in Netbeans, I get "File not found" errors for the .dat file that the bean class needs, and thus the fields are always 0.0.

Here's an excerpt from my bean class:

```
public class Calculations implements Serializable {
    //declare data members
    private double amt[] = new double [100];
    private String cat[] = new String [100];
    public double bankIntReceived;
    private String category;
    private ArrayList <Receipts> rec = new ArrayList<Receipts>();

    public Calculations(){
        rec = new ArrayList<Receipts>();
        loadReceipts();
        category = "";
        bankIntReceived = calcReceipts("Bank Interest Received");
    }

    public double getBankIntReceived() {
        return bankIntReceived;
    }

    public void setBankIntReceived(double bankIntReceived) {
        this.bankIntReceived = bankIntReceived;
    }
```

Any my Factory class:

```
public class BeanFactory implements Serializable {
    //collection for javabeans
    public static Collection getCalcs() {
        Vector calculations = new Vector();
        try {
            Calculations calc = new Calculations();
            calc.getBankIntReceived();
            calculations.add(calc);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return calculations;
    }
}
```

bankIntReceived will always show 0.0. If I set it manually to a different figure it will show up, so it's a problem loading the .dat file.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could get the .dat file to load?

Any help really appreciated! I have been wracking my brain trying to figure this out for the last week. Please excuse any messiness in the code I am a beginner to java. Really would appreciated some help with this!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The file will not load under preview as the program is not running. Once I added the PDF via Jasper to the program and ran it, the figures appeared as they should :)